# Shortest Way to Assign "A or B" to a Variable in Python?

Tags: python, ruby, ternary-operator

Hello Python experts,

I am wondering if there is any shorter way to assign a value "A" to a variable if "A" is True (i.e. exists) and "B" if not.

Suppose I have:

```
mydict = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'banana', 'c': 'Cherry'}
```

Then, as I understand, the shortest (well, one-line) way of assigning a value that does not exist as a key in this mydict var is:

```
myvar = mydict['m'] if 'm' in mydict else 'Melon'
```

But is there any shorter way of doing this?

In Ruby, I would go like this:

```
myvar = mydict[:m] || 'Melon'
```

Just wondering.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: In Ruby `mydict[:m]` presumably returns the equivalent of Python's `None`. How do you store `None` in a Python dict then?

Comment: The Ruby version would appear not to do the same thing. The result of the dictionary lookup being "true" (i.e., satisfying an if-test) is not the same as the value existing in the dictionary. The lookup would be "false" if the value exists but is "false" (`None`, `False`, an empty list, etc. are false-ish values in Python; presumably Ruby is similar).

Comment: @Karl Knechter: Only `false`and `nil` are false in Ruby. Empty arrays or strings, zero - all return true in an if-statement. (Python's `None` is like Ruby's `nil`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this particular case (getting an item from a dictionary), there's a shortcut available - the `get` method, which allows a default value.

```
myvar = mydict.get('m', 'Melon')
```

Comment: Translated back to Ruby, that would be `myvar = mydict.fetch('m', 'Melon')`

Comment: Oh this is more like what I wanted to do! Thank you soo much!

Answer (score 4):

I would consider the use of the [`get()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method to be an improvement on the `if/else` version.

```
myvar = mydict.get('m', 'melon')
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
myvar = mydict.get('m', 'melon')
```

where the second parameter is a default value if the key 'm' cannot be found.

See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html